# Find all triples of non-negative real numbers $(a,b,c)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, systems-of-equations, contest-math

Find all triples of non-negative real numbers $(a,b,c)$ such that:

$a^2+ab=c$

$b^2+bc=a$

$c^2+ca=b$.

This question was problem number of 3 in the RMO(India) Olympiad in 2019 held on $10^{th}$ November. [link](https://www.allen.ac.in/pncf/rmo/pdf/phase-II/RMO-Paper-with-Solution-10-nov.pdf)  .

---

My attempt-

Assume $a \geq b\geq c$,

$\therefore a^2 \geq b^2$ and $ab\geq bc$.

Adding these two, $a^2+ab\geq b^2+bc$

implies $c \geq a$.

Which can be possible only if  $a=c$, which also implies $a=b=c$.

Substituting in the base equations,

$a^2+a^2=a$

$\therefore (a,b,c)=(0,0,0)$ or $(0.5,0.5,0.5)$

I want to know if my method is correct because it seems a lot different than the one provided in the solutions.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Could you explain how $a^2+ab\geq b^2+bc$ implies $c \geq a$? And how your first assumption and $c \geq a$ implies $a=c$?

Comment: it looks correct .

Comment: @Pspl We are given $a^2 + ab = c$ and $b^2 + bc = a$, so the answer to your first question is pure substitution. As for your second question, we already assumed $a\geq b\geq c$. If we also have $c\geq a$, then all these inequalities must be equalities.

Comment: @Arthur, thanks. For some "obscure" reason, I was reading $a \geq c$ instead of $c \geq a$. I guess it's because today is Monday...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not quite convinced by your method.

When we have equations that are completely symmetric in three variables, we can assume any partial order we like without loss of generality.

In this case, however, the equations are only cyclically symmetric in $a,$ $b,$ and $c.$
If you swap $a$ and $b$ you get a different set of equations.

But if you also mention that a similar result occurs when $b\geq a\geq c,$ then you have covered all possible permutations of the variables in the partial order, and I am convinced. Fortunately, a similar result *does* follow.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to point that out.

Answer (score 3):

Your method is not full because the system is cyclic and not symmetric.

You can not assume that $a\geq b\geq c$.

We can solve our system by the following way.

We have: if $a=0$ so $c=0$ and from here $b=0$, which gives a solution $(0,0,0)$.

Thus, it's enough to solve our system for $abc\neq0$ and sice
$$a(a+b)=c,$$
$$b(b+c)=a$$ and $$c(c+a)=b,$$ we obtain:
$$abc\prod_{cyc}(a+b)=abc$$ or
$$\prod_{cyc}(a+b)=1.$$
In another hand, from the starting system we obtain:
$$(a-b)(a+b)=(c-a)(b+1),$$
$$(b-c)(b+c)=(a-b)(c+1)$$ and
$$(c-a)(c+a)=(b-c)(a+1).$$
Thus, $a=b$ gives $c=a$ and we got as you got: $a=b=c,$ which gives also a solution $\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right).$

Now, let $(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)\neq0.$
Thus, from the last system we obtain:
$$\prod_{cyc}(a-b)\prod_{cyc}(a+b)=\prod_{cyc}(a-b)\prod_{cyc}(a+1)$$ or
$$1=\prod_{cyc}(a+1),$$ which is impossible, which gives the answer:
$$\left\{(0,0,0),\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)\right\}$$

Comment: "In another hand, from the starting system we obtain:" I didn't understand this passage. I agree $\prod_{cyc}(a+b)=1$

Answer (score 0):

Eliminating $b,c$ from our system we get for $a$ the following equation:
$$2 a^8+a^7+a^6+3 a^5+6 a^4+2 a^3-a^2-a=0$$
and this is $$a (2 a-1) \left(a^6+a^5+a^4+2 a^3+4 a^2+3 a+1\right)=0$$

Comment: how can one proceed from here?

Comment: I have added a line for you!!

Comment: thank you so much :)

Comment: Does this really address the question? Sure, it may solve the problem, but it doesn't say anything about whether the given approach was good.